# Не срабатывает условие если нет строки в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть запрос в mysql php.
Строки такой нет в таблице и условие не срабатывает.
Просто пустое место. В чем может быть проблема?

```
<?php 
stmt5 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM bp WHERE id=".$row['bp']." LIMIT 1");
while ($row5 = $stmt5->fetch()) {
    if (!empty($row5['name']) && $row5['id']>0) {
    echo "<option selected value='".$row5['id']."'>".$row5['name']."</option>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<option selected value='0'>--</option>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Так всё верно, у вас в условии написано: Пока $stmt что-то возвращает, цикл должен выполнятся, иначе цикл прерывается. И зачем вы вызываете цикл если достаёте 1 запись??

Comment: Вроде бы PDO а вы вставляете в запрос переменную без экранирования... Вроде бы... Что в `$row['bp']` и как оно там должно появится?

Comment: @Walfter в `$row['bp']` находиться id сущности.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
<?php 
$stmt5 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM bp WHERE id=:bp LIMIT 1");
$stmt5->execute(['bp' => $row['bp']]);
$row5 = $stmt5->fetch();

if (!empty($row5['name']) && $row5['id']>0) {
echo "<option selected value='".$row5['id']."'>".$row5['name']."</option>";
}
else {
    echo "<option selected value='0'>--</option>";
}

?>
```

Так же стоит почитать про подготовленные запросы.

Comment: Увы не сработало.